# In numpy append multiple rows using for loop

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, numpy, append

Using numpy arrays, say i have an example array x

```
 [[ 10.   1.   1.   3.   0.   0.]
  [ 11.   1.   1.   3.   0.   0.]
  [ 13.   8.   3.  13.   0.   0.]
  [ 22.   4.   0.  23.   0.   0.]
  [ 32.   6.   0.   8.   0.   0.]
  [ 43.   9.   6.   3.   0.   0.]]
```

and I have a vector, say, y

```
 [34. 56.]
```

How can I use a for loop (or anything faster?) to add rows to x with zeros after, such as

```
     [[ 10.   1.   1.   3.   0.   0.]
      [ 11.   1.   1.   3.   0.   0.]
      [ 13.   8.   3.  13.   0.   0.]
      [ 22.   4.   0.  23.   0.   0.]
      [ 32.   6.   0.   8.   0.   0.]
      [ 43.   9.   6.   3.   0.   0.]
      [ 34.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
      [ 56.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

(it would be additionally great to have them efficiently ordered by the first coln, but not critical here)

thank you for your help

Comment: Here is what i've come up with. I just don't know how efficient this is. Any help is appreciated. thx!

Assumes 6 columns       

x.resize(x.shape[0]+y.shape[0],6)              
x[x.shape[0]-tmpDiff.shape[0]:,0] = y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first create the array you want to add to the bottom of you data array:

```
import numpy as np
D = np.array([[ 10.,   1.,   1.,   3.,   0.,   0.],
           [ 11.,   1.,   1.,   3.,   0.,   0.],
           [ 13.,   8.,   3.,  13.,   0.,   0.],
           [ 22.,   4.,   0.,  23.,   0.,   0.],
           [ 32.,   6.,   0.,   8.,   0.,   0.],
           [ 43.,   9.,   6.,   3.,   0.,   0.]])
A = np.array([34., 56.])

Bottom = np.zeros( (A.shape[0], D.shape[1]) )
Bottom[:,0] = A
```

and now concatenate that part to the old array

```
D = concatenate( [D, Bottom] )
```

alternativly there is the resize function

```
D = np.resize( D, ( D.shape[0]+len(A), D.shape[1] ) )
```

however now you need to make sure that the newly added rows are zero

```
D[-len(A):]
D[-len(A):,0] = A
```

and probably even then the whole array will be copied to a new location, but in some cases you might be lucky and there is enough space in memory just after your original array.

performance wise I don't know what is better. However in general adding to numpy arrays is not such a great idea. Maybe you think along the lines of creating a much bigger array in the beginning and use slicing D[:index_you_need] to display only the rows you actually want at agiven time. Then you could just add the new lines to that big array and update the slice.

If you nedd to add lines a lot maybe you should use python list, they are much more flexible. numpy arrays are the choice if you are planning on doing a lot of number crunching, because that is what they are there for ;-).